# node-red mqtt just connecting

Tags: mqtt, node-red, broker

I have installed node-red at my Raspberry pi 4 and it seems to work fine. My problem is to connect mqtt-output to mqtt-input using rpi4-ip+port (server = test-client@192.168.1.10:1883). The result is that status = connecting.

When I use Server="public broker" status = connected.

Can anyone give me a hint, how to get connected with rpi4-ip+port ?

[image: Simple flow]

[image: mqtt-out Security=empty; Messages=empty]

[image: mqtt-in]

Comment: 1) Are you 100% certain there is a MQTT broker running on 192.168.1.10?  2) if the broker is running is the firewall blocking access to port 1883? 3) What do the Node-RED logs show if you leave it?

Comment: Thanks hardillb
You were right
I did missed the part where I should installed a broker. I was not a part of the tutorial.